# HTML2Canvas: Unable to find element in cloned iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, html2canvas

In my program, I am trying to do a PDF export of some pages, but I encountered the following error when HTML2Canvas tries to process the elements that I have:

Unable to find element in cloned iframe

And only this. This is the code I use:

```
public exportToPdf(
    selectedFilter: SelectedFilter,
    currentTime: string,
    idOfExportDiv: string[]
  ): void {
    this.addClassToMainDiv();

    const elementsToScreenshot: HTMLElement[] = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < idOfExportDiv.length; index++) {
      elementsToScreenshot.push(document.getElementById(idOfExportDiv[index]));
    }

    const fileName = 'export-' + currentTime + '.pdf';
    this.download(elementsToScreenshot, fileName, selectedFilter, currentTime);
  }
```

And the download function:

```
  download(elementById: HTMLElement[], name, selectedFilter: SelectedFilter, currentTime: string) {
    const html2canvasPromises: Promise<unknown>[] = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < elementById.length; index++) {
      html2canvasPromises.push(
        html2canvas(elementById[index], {
          useCORS: true
        }).then(canvas => {
          const image = canvas.toDataURL();
          const imagePromise = this.addImage(image);
          return imagePromise;
        })
      );
    }

    Promise.all(html2canvasPromises)
      .then(content => {
        this.removeClassFromMainDiv();
        this.downloadPdf(selectedFilter, currentTime, name, content);
        this.pdfCreated.next(true);
        this.loadingSpinnerService.close();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Image conversion error', 'Failed to screenshot and download provided elements', {
          error: error
        });
        this.removeClassFromMainDiv();
        this.pdfCreated.next(true);
        this.loadingSpinnerService.close();
      });
  }
```

The "elementsToScreenshot" is an array of HTMLElements that is always filled with the correct found elements inside the HTML rendering, which look like this:

```
0: div#main-screen-export-div.m-l-20.m-top-15.wrapper-comp
1: div#export-main-0.d-flex.w-100.ng-star-inserted
2: div#export-main-1.d-flex.w-100.ng-star-inserted
3: div#export-main-2.d-flex.w-100.ng-star-inserted
```

Since I use Angular and I need some dynamically set ids, the ids of the 1,2 and 3 divs are set like this in HTML:

```
<div [id]="'export-main-' + index"></div>
```

I have no iframes in my program, trackers, or other 3rd party injectors like google ads,
Did anyone else encounter this problem before and knows how to fix it?

EDIT: Maybe this proves helpful. This is the file where the error probably triggers, since I found this exact error in there:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/src/index.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue in the end

The nesting of the HTML looked like this:

```html
<div data-html2canvas-ignore="true">
   <div>
      <div id="export-main-0"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue was that one of the parent divs had that data-html2canvas-ignore tag applied on it, which made the child div being undetectable by the html2canvas. Simply removing the ignore rule from the parent div made everything work again.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to clone the node and add elements or styles,

Try **onclone** like this:

```
html2canvas(elementById[index], {
    onclone: function (documentClone) {

        var headnode = document.createElement("h1");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello World');  
        headnode.appendChild(textnode);

        documentClone.querySelector('#list').prepend(headnode)
        (<HTMLElement>documentClone.querySelector('body')).style.padding = '30px';
      }
  }).then(canvas => {
     ...
})
```